# Fail to deploy a NodeJS app on azure

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, git-bash

I'm trying to deploy a nodejs webapp in azure using git-bash (on windows). I have followed the [following tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started) and get stuck when I do the following command (bullet number 5): `azure site create --git {appname}`. I get the following output:

```
info:    Executing command site create
error:   The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.
error:   Error information has been recorded to C:\Users\myname\.azure\azure.err
error:   site create command failed
```

Can't find a clear solution online on how to solve this issue...

**Edit**: Here is the error file content:

```
2016-12-01T13:49:38.217Z:
{ Error: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.
  <<< async stack >>>
  at getSites__7 (C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-cli\lib\commands\asm\websites\websitesclient.js:460:24)
  at determineIfSiteAndSlotExists (C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-cli\lib\commands\asm\site.js:282:30)
  at __4 (C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-cli\lib\commands\asm\site.js:229:11)
  <<< raw stack >>>
    at Function.ServiceClient._normalizeError (C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-cli\node_modules\azure-common\lib\services\serviceclient.js:814:23)
    at C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-cli\node_modules\azure-common\lib\services\filters\errorhandlingfilter.js:44:29
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-cli\node_modules\azure-common\lib\http\request-pipeline.js:109:14)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-cli\node_modules\request\request.js:187:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-cli\node_modules\request\request.js:1044:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-cli\node_modules\request\request.js:965:12)
  stack: [Getter],
  code: 'ForbiddenError',
  statusCode: 403,
  __frame: 
   { name: 'getSites__7',
     line: 455,
     file: 'C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\azure-cli\\lib\\commands\\asm\\websites\\websitesclient.js',
     prev: 
      { name: 'determineIfSiteAndSlotExists',
        line: 280,
        file: 'C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\azure-cli\\lib\\commands\\asm\\site.js',
        prev: [Object],
        calls: 1,
        active: false,
        offset: 2,
        col: 29 },
     calls: 0,
     active: false,
     offset: 5,
     col: 23 },
  rawStack: [Getter] }
Error: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.
  <<< async stack >>>
  at getSites__7 (C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-cli\lib\commands\asm\websites\websitesclient.js:460:24)
  at determineIfSiteAndSlotExists (C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-cli\lib\commands\asm\site.js:282:30)
  at __4 (C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-cli\lib\commands\asm\site.js:229:11)
  <<< raw stack >>>
    at Function.ServiceClient._normalizeError (C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-cli\node_modules\azure-common\lib\services\serviceclient.js:814:23)
    at C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-cli\node_modules\azure-common\lib\services\filters\errorhandlingfilter.js:44:29
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-cli\node_modules\azure-common\lib\http\request-pipeline.js:109:14)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-cli\node_modules\request\request.js:187:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-cli\node_modules\request\request.js:1044:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-cli\node_modules\request\request.js:965:12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the following steps will help.

1, Change into ASM mode and log in to Azure under Azure CLI:

```
azure config mode asm
azure login
```

2, Download your subscription file with the command below:

```
azure account download
```

3, Run the following command to import the subscription file which you have downloaded:

```
azure account import 'C:\Users\me\Downloads\xxx.publishsettings'
```

4, Create a new Web app that is initialized with a Git repository:

```
azure site create --git {appname}
```

Comment: Thanks but I've already tried that and whenever I do `azure account download` I fall on a webpage saying “No subscriptions found for Azure Account”. Please note that I'm the "Owner"...I've also tried to copy the link in an incognito browser and logged in with the "Owner" credentials - still getting the same error

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to create a web app in Azure App Service by using the Azure Portal. Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac for details.